# Не выводится цветной текст в input через модуль colorama

Tags: python, colorama

Пользуюсь модулем "colorama" для того чтоб приукрасить свою программу.

Возникает такая проблема. Не хочет работать именно там где есть input. То есть в других случаях вывода все работает. А при попытке разукрасить текст в input не работает выводит такие символы:[30m[47mВ и не цветной текст. Вот пример(код не весь, только верхняя часть и одна из проблемных:

```
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style, init
init(autoreset=True)
z = str(input(Back.GREEN + Fore.WHITE + "текст: "))
```

Результат:

```
[42m[37m текст:
```

Comment: Не бойтесь форматировать код вопроса. Я его подправил, а вы сами в следующий раз :)

Comment: Он изначально так и выглядел, но после публикации почему-то стал таким)

Comment: Действительно, при первой версии публикации было форматирование, но на третьей версии правки от вас форматирование пропало. Рекомендую, использовать символы \`\`\` перед и после блока кода, вместо использования пробелов :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На английском SO [обсуждался этот вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32872612/python-colorama-not-working-with-input), это известная проблема, проще всего обойти её, не используя управляющие символы `colorama` в `input`, код это увеличивает не сильно, зато в `print` они работают стабильно:

```
print(Back.GREEN + Fore.WHITE + "текст: ", end='')
z = input()
```

Но по ссылке есть и другие варианты (некоторым помогает импорт каких-то ещё библиотек), можете их попробовать.

Comment: Благодарю, все заработало;)

Answer (score 2):

У меня os.system("cls") в начале кода исправляет эту проблему.

```
from colorama import Fore
import os
os.system("cls")
input(Fore.GREEN + 'text')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Хм, как ни странно это работает. Но только на Windows 10.